# PHP | Вопрос по переменным и file_get_contents

Tags: php

Как здесь исправить ошибку? Код:

```
$b = 'Gg_Gg'
    $homepage1 = file_get_contents('https://exemple.com/code='$b'');
echo $homepage1;
exit;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

точку с запятой поставить в конце первой строки

```
$b = 'Gg_Gg';
$homepage1 = file_get_contents('https://exemple.com/code='$b'');
echo $homepage1;
exit;
```

Comment: $homepage1 = file_get_contents('https://exemple.com/code='.$b);

Comment: а точку с запятой я и не заметил =) кавычки поправьте лучше в ответе, а не в комментарии =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$b = "Gg_Gg";
$homepage1 = file_get_contents("https://example.com/code=".$b);
echo $homepage1;
exit;
```

Answer (score -2):

Вот так:

```
$b = 'Gg_Gg';
    $homepage1 = file_get_contents('https://exemple.com/code='.$b.'');
echo $homepage1;
exit;
```

Или так:

```
$b = 'Gg_Gg';
    $homepage1 = file_get_contents("https://exemple.com/code='$b'");
echo $homepage1;
exit;
```

Или так:

```
$b = 'Gg_Gg';
    $homepage1 = file_get_contents("https://exemple.com/code=$b");
echo $homepage1;
exit;
```

Все зависит от того какая именно у вас была ошибка.(скорее всего ваш вариант - 3)